# Checkmark "Connect Via Network" in physical device

Tags: xcode, debugging, usb-debugging, xcode15

[image: Screen from xcode "Devices And Simulators"]

After update XCode from 14.3 to 15.0 i have this mistake that i cannot disable "Connect Via Network" in physical device.

Also device connect via cabel

How can I disable "Connect Via Network" from device if this checkbox has gray color..

XCode 15.0 version, Device iPhone 11 iOS 17.0 version

**UPD:**

Post on Apple Developer https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/737875?login=true

**UPD:**

[Xcode 15.0.1 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-15_0_1-release-notes)

[image]

Comment: Same problem. And it seems the feature is significantly slowing debugging.

Comment: @AlexSh. Yes, it takes a critical time while the app is launching….

Comment: Maybe the problems are related to an outdated device, @AlexSh. , what kind of device do you have?

Comment: And apple released ios 17.0.1 

Comment: no, I have 12 Pro and M2 macbook so it's definitely not the outdated device problem :-) And on 14.3 xcode version everything was fine. Also I faced the slowed down debugging previously while using 'connect via network' option, so I think this is the reason. I mean it takes too long time to 'jump' from one breakpoint to another.

Comment: Yep, on 14.3 xcode all works fine

Answer (score 9):

Same problem; it seems to be a bug in iOS or Xcode.

Running Xcode 15.0 (15A240d) from Mac AppStore, and it looks like it only happens to devices running 17.0.0 and 17.0.1. Devices running 16.7 can still use wire to debug, and the "Connect via network" checkbox is functional.

I filed a bug report here https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/form-response/31792610 I hope those who facing the same issue can file a report as well to encourage Apple to fix it ASAP.

**Update Oct 17,2023**: while it has not been fixed by Apple, the workaround in the developer forum worked for me: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/737875?answerId=768846022#768846022

1. Plug in your device without Xcode running
2. Launch Xcode

**Update Dec 19, 2023**: this is still an issue with iOS 17.2.1 and Xcode 15.2; a better workaround is posted in the developer forum: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/737875?answerId=773300022#773300022

1. Disconnect Wi-Fi
2. Launch Xcode and run debug
3. Re-enable Wi-Fi
4. Run debug again

If you can disable the VPN on your macOS, make sure you do so; the VPN connection seems to create a lot of problems

Comment: Not sure why :( I tried again and it works. Perhaps link to Apple ID? Maybe try without the number in the link

Comment: The workaround proposed on dev forums (first plug the device, then launch Xcode) doesn't work for me.

Comment: Hi @kelin, give this new workaround a shot: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/737875?answerId=773300022#773300022; unfortunately, it is still an issue for iOS 15.2.1 and Xcode 15.2

Comment: It's still an issue for iOS 17.0.3 and Xcode 15.2...

Answer (score 2):

Temporary solution.

Try this:

1. Turn on Airplane Mode on device
2. Run your app from Xcode.
3. Turn off Airplane Mode on device.

Source:
**Xcode 15, how to uncheck "Connect via network" for physical device? - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/737875?answerId=773300022#773300022**

Answer (score 0):

Get an Application Firewall such as [LuLu](https://objective-see.org/products/lulu.html) and disable all connections for Xcode.

Edit: this stopped working for me at some point. I hope Apple fixes this.

Comment: For me, it makes impossible to launch the app on an iPhone. Xcode fails at the step of attaching to the debugger and shows an error.

Comment: You hope that Apple fixes that, but it looks more like Apple prepares to disable development through cable.